# Error: The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.>, :backtrace=>["org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:466)", "org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:195)", "org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(org/postgresql/core/ConnectionFactory.java:66)", "org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:127)", "org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc3/AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)", "org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc3g/AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)", "org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:41)", "org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(org/postgresql/jdbc4/Jdbc4Connection.java:24)", "org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(org/postgresql/Driver.java:414)", "org.postgresql.Driver.connect(org/postgresql/Driver.java:282)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606)", "RUBY.connect(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:222)", "RUBY.make_new(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:110)", "RUBY.make_new(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:226)", "RUBY.available(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:199)", "RUBY._acquire(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:135)", "RUBY.acquire(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:149)", "RUBY.sync(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:280)", "org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149)", "RUBY.sync(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:280)", "RUBY.acquire(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:148)", "RUBY.hold(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:106)", "RUBY.synchronize(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:256)", "RUBY.test_connection(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:266)", "RUBY.prepare_jdbc_connection(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.0.2/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:170)", "RUBY.register(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:167)", "RUBY.start_inputs(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:330)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RUBY.start_inputs(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:329)", "RUBY.start_workers(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:180)", "RUBY.run(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136)", "RUBY.start_pipeline(C:/logstash-2.3.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:473)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"], :level=>:error}
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
```

Comment: What is your question? Please show how you start your logstash process.

Comment: Question: How to resolve given error?
Logstash Start Process: open Command prompt > Set Logstash path > Execute config(.cnfg) file. Error: io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated.
The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Comment: What is the command you execute to start logstash? What OS are you using? *NIX, MacOS, Windows?

Comment: No any command, i used to start Logstash. Simply i set the path for logstash bin in command prompt and execute config file. Like - (C:\logstash-2.3.4\bin>logstash -f config1.conf ). And i am using Windows 10.